# High power 12v regulator

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, rgb, high-current

Hi i am new to the forum and this is my first question so fell free to help me with formatting.

I am working on a project that involves controlling RGB LED strips from a Arduino. I have as my power supply a 18.5V 6.5A power-brick. I need to have a regulator to generate 12V at at least 6A. Any suggestions on components or premade boards? I am open to DIY solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are talking about 6 amps and over 6Volts of voltage drop.  That's close to 40Watts of waste heat.  You probably ought to look into buck converters, or just purchase as 12V 6A power brick.

Comment: As JRE pointed out, you can't --and must not-- use a linear regulator. An SMPS is the best option. But designing a 12V buck converter needs a lot of work due to high complexity and component count. So the best option is to buy a 12V power supply. I'm sure you can find in Digikey or Mouser.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the LED strips you want to drive. Just because your power supply is rated at 6.5 Amps doesn't mean you need to have a 6 amp converter to drive your load(s) if they require a lower current. Describe these LED strips, how many you will use in your project, and provide as many specs as you can for them, preferably a data sheet link.

Comment: @RohatKılıç _"... you can't ... use a linear regulator ..."_ - Huh? Sure you can, you just need to dissipate ~40W of heat. There are better approaches, but that doesn't mean he can't.

Comment: @marcelm Of course I know and everyone does :) You are right but in that comment I meant "Practically you can't because of excessive amount of heat". There's also a recommendation ("mustn't" in dashes). Dissipation of nearly 40W of heat can be practically nearly impossible for an amateur DIYer.

Comment: @RohatKılıç _"You are right but in that comment I meant "Practically you can't because of excessive amount of heat"."_ - Fair enough :) I'd prefer prefer just "mustn't" or "shouldn't" though. _"Dissipation of nearly 40W of heat can be practically nearly impossible for an amateur DIYer."_ - Hmm, I'm not sure about that. CPU heatsink + fan + some thermal paste? Not that he _should_ :P

Comment: I am driving a RGB LED strip and when fully white draws 6A for a 5M section. I won't need 6A usally but when at white I want the strip to operate within spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google "12V 6A buck regulator" and select the image tab you will find designs like this: -

[image]

And, of course, different key words produce different results. Searching on that page also comes up with pre-made solutions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick reply! Pointed me in the right direction.